# Remove selected option from new added ListBox

Tags: jquery

I have a ListBox and a button that allows me to add new box lists with the same values as the first one (something like this)

I'm using jQuery to add the new ListBox. The problem is: I want to hide the selected options when I add a new ListBox dynamically.

```js
var nextElementId= 1;
$(function(){
  var table = $('#table');
  $('#addRow').on('click',function(event){
     nextElementId++;
     var newRow = '<select name = "selectbox'+nextElementId+'" id ="'+nextElementId+'">'+
                      '<option value = "1">1</option>'+
                      '<option value = "2">2</option>'+
                      '<option value = "3">3</option>'+
                      '<option value = "4">4</option>'+
                   '</select>';
     $(newRow).appendTo(table);
     $('select').on('change',function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
         $('select').not(this).each(function(){
             $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').remove();
         });
      });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "table" name = "table">
       <select id = "selectbox1" name = "selectbox1">
           <option value = "1">1</option>
           <option value = "2">2</option>
           <option value = "3">3</option>
           <option value = "4">4</option>
       </select>
       <button id = "addRow" name = "addRow">Add Row</button>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lamyae/1hm2gufw/

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I have add changes in your code. I hope it will works for you.**

```js
var nextElementId= 1;
$(function(){
  var table = $('#table');
  $('#addRow').on('click',function(event){
     nextElementId++;
     var ne  = [];
      $('select').each(function(){
           ne.push( $(this).find('option:selected').attr('value'));
         });
     var newRow = '<select name = "selectbox'+nextElementId+'" id ="'+nextElementId+'">'+
                      '<option value = "1">1</option>'+
                      '<option value = "2">2</option>'+
                      '<option value = "3">3</option>'+
                      '<option value = "4">4</option>'+
                   '</select>';
     $(newRow).appendTo(table);
for(var i=0; i < ne.length;i++){
console.log(ne[i])
$('#table select:last-child').find('option[value='+ne[i]+']').remove();
}
if($('#table select:last-child option').length == 0){
$('#table select:last-child').remove();
}

     $('select').on('change',function(){
         var value = $(this).val();
         $('select').not(this).each(function(){
             $(this).find('option[value='+value+']').remove();
         });
      });
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id = "table" name = "table">
       <select id = "selectbox1" name = "selectbox1">
           <option value = "1">1</option>
           <option value = "2">2</option>
           <option value = "3">3</option>
           <option value = "4">4</option>
       </select>
       <button id = "addRow" name = "addRow">Add Row</button>
    </div>
```